# How can I set height of Material-UI Tabs component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set the height of a [Material-UI Tabs component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) to 32px. I know this isn't a great UX idea, but, I've explained that and the customer still wants it.

I tried setting the height on the Tabs component itself. Then on the Tab components inside it. The latter fixes the height to 32px, but the labels are too far down as there's an inner div that is (still) set to 48px.

The line in the [source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Tabs/Tab.js) appears to be:

```
height: (props.label && props.icon) ? 72 : 48,
```

I can't work out how to override that inner div using the styles and themes exposed via Material-UI.

Comment: Completely anecdotal, but `material-ui` is tough to customize - and per the source, they don't appear to be allowing you to override the height with `props`, which is pretty common. I've even seen certain components wrapped with simple `<div>`s, and there's simply no way to effect change on its inner contents. Pretty hamstrung. In some cases, I just fell back to using plain CSS: http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

Comment: Indeed. I looked around for mobile UI options, but couldn't find anything that didn't seem to have issue. grommet looked promising, but MUI had more SO traffic, so I plumped for that. Thinking Kendo might be worth a look when they get the React stuff done.

Comment: glad to see it's not just me ...

Comment: Can you try like this.
`<Tabs tabItemContainerStyle={{height:50 }}>
    <Tab buttonStyle={{height:50}} />
 </Tabs>
`

Answer (score 5):

```
const tabHeight = '24px' // default: '48px'
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  tabsRoot: {
    minHeight: tabHeight,
    height: tabHeight
  },
  tabRoot: {
    minHeight: tabHeight,
    height: tabHeight

  }
}));

<Tabs
  classes={{
    root: classes.tabsRoot,
  }}>
 <Tab
   classes={{
     root: classes.tabRoot
   }} />
 <Tab
   classes={{
     root: classes.tabRoot
    }} />
 <Tab
   classes={{
     root: classes.tabRoot
    }} />
</Tabs
```

Technique based on 'Customizing Components' Option 1: [Overriding styles with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)

Answer (score 1):

I added the inline styling component like so:

```
<Tabs
  style={{height: "32px"}}
>
```

This worked for me, hope it works for you as well

Source:
https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Comment: Doesn't work in MUI V4 because there is `minHeight` set to `48px` somewhere in an internal component. You will have to override it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be apply globally. You can add into the theme provider as overrides.

See the example for the tab :

```
import {createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        minHeight: 70
      }
    }
  }
});

// Under App 

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    ....
  </MuiThemeProvider>
)
```

See the doc for more information [material-ui globals](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify height of Tabs component by adding sx property defining both minHeight and height. It needs to be both.

```html
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  aria-label="Navigation tabs"
  sx={{ minHeight: "30px", height: "30px" }}
></Tabs>
```